# Disabling electric-indent-mode for one mode (latex mode) only

Tags: major-mode, minor-mode

I don't like the way electric indent mode works in latex-mode. Everywhere else (at least everywhere I use), it's great.

How can I permanently disable electric indent mode for latex mode only, but keep it everywhere else?

I'm guessing it's a one-line lisp hack in my config file, or something like that, but I'm horrible at lisp, so I can't figure it out.

Comment: If you want to disable electric indent in a single latex *file*, then add `% -*- electric-indent-inhibit: t -*-
` at the top and run `M-x normal-mode`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command you need is `electric-indent-local-mode`. You can use this to turn off electric-indent-mode in any buffer by calling it manually: `M-x electric-indent-local-mode`. This is a toggle, so calling it again in the same buffer turns it back on again.

To do this automatically from your init file, you need to set up a hook. First, define the hook:

```
(defun remove-electric-indent-mode ()
  (electric-indent-local-mode -1))
```

Then add it to the appropriate mode hooks. To turn off electric-indent-mode for the LaTeX mode provided by AUCTex, use this:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'remove-electric-indent-mode)
```

For the default texmode, use:

```
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'remove-electric-indent-mode)
```

The same pattern holds for any other mode you want to turn off electric indentation.

For more details on mode hooks, see the built-in Emacs manual node `[(emacs) Hooks][1]`. You can get there from Emacs via `C-h i r m Hooks <enter>`: `C-h` for help, `i` for info, `r` for read the manual, `m` for menu item, and `Hooks` to pick the menu item. (or you can follow the link above to see the html version).

Comment: You don’t need to define an extra function: `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-indent-local-mode -1)))` suffices.

Comment: True, but if you define a function, you can reuse it in multiple different hooks without duplicating code. It's also easier to remove a defined function than an anonymous one. That can be useful when debugging